# How to call method properly

Tags: java, loops, methods, mean

So I have this method for mean, my goal is to have the user enter one grade at a time, and the dialog box pops up after each grade is entered, after they are finished they hit okay with nothing or cancel and it populates the mean text field. I am having trouble figuring out how to put in the correct parameters for this method, as I need to parse the string they enter into a double array so that the method can properly calculate.
This is the method below:

```
public double getAverage (double [] gradeArray, int numElem) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i < numElem; i++){
        sum = sum + gradeArray[i];
    }
    return (sum / numElem);

}
```

Here is my code attempting to take the string and put it into the method. Clearly wrong, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around the whole thing. I am not sure how to get my numElem argument to be the correct number, as it changes depending on how many grades the user inputs.
This is my code for the button pushed to calculate:

```
private void btnGradesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
int numElem = 0;
String s = "";

double[] gradesArray;
gradesArray = new double[25];

int i;
do {
 s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter grades:", "Enter grades",                      JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (s == null || s.equals("")) {
 if (s == null)
 {
     s = "";
 }

String total2 = String.valueOf(avg);
txtMean.setText(total2);


} else { 


for(i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    gradesArray[i] = Double.parseDouble (s);

   numElem++;
}

avg = getAverage (gradesArray, numElem);
}
} // end Do 
while (!s.equals(""));
```

}

Comment: I think you want to pass length of array then use `gradesArray.length()`

Comment: use gradeArray.length(), not a parameter for the length.

Comment: @RedAlert He's not dynamically sizing his array, it has a size of 25 but not all members are grades, so he can't do that.

Comment: Devin, Welcome to SO! Can you please post a *complete* example that recreates the problem which you are asking about? By "complete", I mean that it needs to have enough code that I (and others) can simply copy and paste the code and it will have the exact same effect that you are asking about (whether that is a specific compiler error or actual output when you run the program). Also be sure to trim out any code that is unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Jean-Bernard Pellerin How are all not all members grades? If you look at the loop that sets `gradesArray`, it queries for all 25 inputs before it continues. His `numElem` increment is also in the wrong place, but it would just be getting set to 25 no matter what anyways.

Comment: @Code-Guru Gotcha, fixed it. sorry about that.

Comment: @RedAlert I am pretty sure my issue is in the for loop, should i change the 25 to the variable numElem so that is does not always look for 25 values?, also where should my increment be?

Comment: I assume you want to increment numElem every time you add an element to the array, so it should be inside your for loop, not outside. The way you have it set up there's no point in even having `numElem` though, since you are forcing the user to enter 25 grades no matter what, so `numElem` will always end up as 25.

Comment: @RedAlert I do not want to force the user to put in 25 grades, I want them to only put in as many as they want and it still calculate properly. I understand what your saying though. What would you suggest so that it does not force them to enter 25 grades and any amount they want, whether it be 3 4 10, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many grades the student has entered. You can do this with a variable that starts at 0 and gets incremented every time the student enters a grade correctly. You can then pass that value as numElem.

Comment: I added this into the code, and it for some reason only shoots out the last number they entered as the mean.

Comment: @Devin try using return (sum / (Double)numElem);

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you'd want to do:

```
s = ... //ask user to input number of grades here
numElem = Int.parseInt (s)

for(i=0; i<numElem; i++)
{
    s = ... //prompt for next grade
    gradesArray[i] = Double.parseDouble (s);    
}
```

You can initialize gradesArray to be bigger as well to account for more possibilities, maybe 100 or something. Just make sure the numElem input isn't greater than the initialized size.